# Uploading PNG image with AFAmazonS3Manager - Invalid Headers

Tags: image, amazon-s3, afnetworking

I'm posting an image to Amazon S3 using mattt's AFAmazonS3Manager [library](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFAmazonS3Client), basically by  following the example there. The upload works fine, but when I download the file from S3, it has those headers that make the file invalid.

```
--Boundary+37BFEC640AAEA6AB
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="key"

test.png
--Boundary+37BFEC640AAEA6AB
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename=".png"
Content-Type: image/png

âPNG


IHDR,êu]{iDOT»(»»-0∫´@IDATx\ΩÂü◊πÆ≠ø‚ÏΩOíùƒ(ã,Àñôb;vÏƒÃ33Ãh4ÃÃÃ‘C›”√åb∂d…≤dvÃ±„Äì≥˜9ÔóÁΩÓUS≤≤?<øµ™jUUwO◊’˜kÕ¨≥Côv~4«Nd⁄©¡,,€NÂÿÒ˛l;÷ómSΩÖnH¥ÜÚ8k≠I¥æñTÌÃ≤Èû

...
```

When I remove the headers, the file becomes valid and I can open it with Preview or Photoshop.

The code to create the image is as follow:

```
// Save image to Amazon S3. Save URL for user dictionary.
    NSData *pngImage = UIImagePNGRepresentation(profilePicture);
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *imagePath =[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.png", chatIdString]];
    if ([pngImage writeToFile:imagePath atomically:NO]) {
        NSLog(@"Successfully cached profile picture to %@.", imagePath);
        AFAmazonS3Manager *s3Manager = [[AFAmazonS3Manager alloc] initWithAccessKeyID:AWSAccessKeyId secret:AWSSecretKey];
        s3Manager.responseSerializer = [AFOnoResponseSerializer XMLResponseSerializer];
        s3Manager.requestSerializer.region = AFAmazonS3USStandardRegion;
        s3Manager.requestSerializer.bucket = @"checkchat";
        [s3Manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"image/png" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

        [s3Manager putObjectWithFile:imagePath...
```

I'm using a PUT request, as per Amazon S3's REST API reference. Any idea what I could do to store a valid image on S3?